# Tracking a Robot in circular motion

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, computer-science

I have to write a program to predict the location of a robot that's moving in a circle(well, almost circle). I'm getting sensor measurements(they could be with or without noise, both.) from the robot, its current (x,y) coordinates. I'm aware of how I might use Kalman or Particle filters to track the bot, but I have seen that people have been able to use arc tangent, distance between two measurements, and then 'cos' and 'sin' of the angle multiplied by the distance to predict the next point. Can anyone please help me understand the intuition behind this technique?

Here's the algorithm:

```
delta_y = current-point(y-coordinate) - previous_point(y-coordinate)

delta_x = current-point(x-coordinate) - previous_point(x-coordinate)


current_angle = atan2(delta_y, delta_x) //arc-tangent

turn_angle = current_angle - previous_angle

heading_direction = current_angle + turn_angle

distance = distance of(current_point, original_point)
x_predicted = current_point(x-coordinate) + distance * cos(heading_direction)

y_predicted = current_point(y-cooridnate) + distance * sin(heading_direction)
```

Regards,

Comment: assuming the robot is on the same circle the value of the radius doesn't change and equals $r=\sqrt{y^2+x^2}$, then 
(x_predicted,y_predicted) = (r*cos(heading_direction),r*sin(heading_direction))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(x,y)=(r\cos \theta,r\sin\theta)$$
given that your robot is moving on circle all you need is an angle. 
Since $\theta = \arctan(x,y)$ you can know the angle or the difference in angle between two subsequent measurements which give you a sort of velocity measurements which you can use to predict the next point.

Hope this makes sense.

Hint: use $\arctan 2$ instead of $\arctan$ it is usually in many math libraries, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).

Comment: I'll break down my confusion: 
To apply atan2 in this situation, why do we need the difference(not distance) between two measurements? How this difference and later the angle helps us predict the future location?

Comment: The distance in this situation is a function of difference in angle. Think about the following scenario, the robot moves $1^\circ$ each measurement in the same direction, where he will be on next measurement?

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. Is this difference between measurements the arc length on the circle and when arc tangent is applied on it, it gives us the angle? 

I'll use a small example to understand exactly, I hope that's ok? 

Measurement 1 -- [2,3]
Measurement 2 -- [4,5]

Difference = (4-2, 5-3)
Now, we take this difference and calculate arc tangent on the difference. So, this difference is the arc length and arc tangent function gives us the angle?

Comment: nope, based on your example, assuming that in the brackets you have $x,y$ coordinates,   you'll need $Difference = \arctan(4,5)-\arctan(2,3)$

Comment: I think I see where my confusion lies. I have implemented a given algorithm that predicts the point and its working alright. I'm trying to understand that. I have included it in my initial post now because of message limit here. Can you please help me understand that?